# Count occurrences on a array using MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining the number of occurrences of each unique element in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385651/determining-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-unique-element-in-a-vector)

I've the following array:

```
v = [ 1 5 1 6 7 1 5 5 1 1]
```

And I need to count the values and show the number that has more appearances.

From the example on the top, the solution would be 1 (there are five 1's)

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jonas: This might be simpler than that

Comment: other similar questions: [Calculate most common values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846635), [How can I count the number of elements of a given value in a matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880933), [Is there a more elegant replacement for this MATLAB loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427291), [function to determine pmf (X) in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068403)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`mode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mode.html).

If you need to return the number of elements as well, do the following:

```
m = mode(v);
n = sum(v==m);
fprintf('%d appears %d times\n',m,n);
```

Answer (score 9):

Another method is using the `hist` function, if you're dealing with integers.

```
numbers=unique(v);       %#provides sorted unique list of elements
count=hist(v,numbers);   %#provides a count of each element's occurrence
```

Just make sure you specify an output value for the hist function, or you'll end up with a bar graph.

Answer (score 1):

@Jacob is right: `mode(v)` will give you the answer you need.

I just wanted to add a nice way to represent the frequencies of each value:

```
bar(accumarray(v', 1))
```

will show a nice bar diagram with the count of each value in `v`.